# assign empty parenthesis to a String reference variable

Tags: java, oop, object, reference

What happens when assigning empty parentheses value to a String in Java?

```
String s = "";
```

Does the object reference variable s refer to an object in the heap memory carrying a String value of nothing?

what made me ask this question is that when printing the hash code of the object I get a zero, which did not make sense to me!

```
System.out.println("hash code is = " + s.hashCode());
```

hash code is = 0

Answer (score 6):

From the String doc :

> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String
>   object is computed as
>        s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]

and since your string is empty it will result with 0.

Answer (score 3):

Look into `String.hashCode()` for calculation and it will make sense...

From Java 1.8

```java
/** Cache the hash code for the string */
private int hash; // Default to 0

...

public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The doc says it all: the hashcode depends directly on the String value, and the calculations make it 0 for an empty String.

If you have some doubts with what hashcode does exactly for Strings, it might be helpful to check its implementation [there](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29).

That **does not mean there is no object** in the heap representing your String.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of hashCode fro String.

```
 /**
         * Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a
         * <code>String</code> object is computed as
         * <blockquote><pre>
         * s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
         * </pre></blockquote>
         * using <code>int</code> arithmetic, where <code>s[i]</code> is the
         * <i>i</i>th character of the string, <code>n</code> is the length of
         * the string, and <code>^</code> indicates exponentiation.
         * (The hash value of the empty string is zero.) // look at this line
         *
         * @return  a hash code value for this object.
         */
        public int hashCode() {// some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java?av=f):

```
if (h == 0 && count > 0) { 
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       h = 31*h + val[off++];
   }
   ...
}
return h; //0
```

The String is empty, the result is 0. See also the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()):

[image]

Comment: image for documentation citation? really? :-/

Comment: @Betlista Well.. I still don't know why I did that.

Answer (score 1):

With that you instantiate an empty string and assign it to the variable `s`

from http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html you have

```
/** Cache the hash code for the string */
 private int hash; // Default to 0

public int hashCode() {
 int h = hash;
 if (h == 0 && count > 0) {
 int off = offset;
 char val[] = value;
 int len = count;

 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 h = 31*h + val[off++];
 }
 hash = h;
 }
 return h;
 }
```

this returns 0 if `count == 0` (empty string)

Answer (score 1):

yes, String s = "" will take space in the memory.

Regarding the hashcode calculation, below is the hashcode method of String class. "hash" has a default value of 0; The if condition

```
if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
```

Fails so you are getting 0 as hashcode value.

public int hashCode() {
int h = hash;
    int len = count;
if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        h = 31*h + val[off++];
    }
    hash = h;
}
return h;
```

}